# Failed to deploy a persistent Composer REST server

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I've followed these tutorials:

1. Deploying to multiple orgs (https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org), then
2. Deploying persistent REST server (https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/deploying-the-rest-server)

And I got this error on the last step when I started a Docker image for the REST server:

```
Connection fails: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/ca.crt'
```

I assumed that the Docker image cannot access the `crypto-config` folder because it's at `~/path/to/project/fabric/crypto-config`, so I copied/pasted it around, for example, `/home/.composer/crypto-config`, `~/crypto-config`. But it didn't help.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right lines for trying to make the crypto certs available inside the container, but I think you need to map an extra volume on the `docker run` command.
`-v ~/path/to/project/fabric/crypto-config:/home/composer/crypto-config \`

(When you move to Composer v.0.17.* and Fabric v1.1.0 then you will be able to include the pem certificate directly in the connection.json so the problem will go away - this is the modified tutorial for v0.17.* - [Multi-org Tutorial for v0.17.*](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/next-unstable/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I used `-v ~/path/to/project/fabric/crypto-config:/home/composer/crypto-config \'`, but it gave another error `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/composer/.composer/cards/alice@tutorial-network'`. However, I'll just run the REST server process in the background, which is enough for me now.